# keep svg centered when scaling up the background circle

Tags: html, svg, tailwind-css

I want to use [this sample svg icon](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sschoger/heroicons-ui/master/svg/icon-rocket.svg) with a circle background. I took some HTML code on how to do it from the DOM from [this link](https://tailwindcss.com/screencasts/)

So currently I have this result and as you can see the icon is as big as the background circle.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.1.4/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-shrink-0" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" class="text-green-200 fill-current"></circle>
  <path class="text-green-600 fill-current" d="M16.21 16.95a5 5 0 0 1-4.02 4.9l-3.85.77a1 1 0 0 1-.9-.27l-.71-.7a2 2 0 0 1 0-2.83l1.44-1.45a13.17 13.17 0 0 1-1.42-1.41L5.31 17.4a2 2 0 0 1-2.83 0l-.7-.7a1 1 0 0 1-.28-.9l.77-3.86a5 5 0 0 1 4.9-4.02h.86a13.07 13.07 0 0 1 12.82-5.47 1 1 0 0 1 .83.83A12.98 12.98 0 0 1 16.2 16.1v.85zm-4.41 2.94a3 3 0 0 0 2.41-2.94v-1.4a1 1 0 0 1 .47-.84A11.04 11.04 0 0 0 19.8 4.33 10.98 10.98 0 0 0 9.42 9.45a1 1 0 0 1-.85.47h-1.4a3 3 0 0 0-2.94 2.4l-.66 3.34.33.33 2.24-2.24a1 1 0 0 1 1.52.12 11.08 11.08 0 0 0 2.6 2.6 1 1 0 0 1 .12 1.52l-2.24 2.24.33.33 3.33-.67zM15 10a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z" />
</svg>
```

I would like to have some inner circle margin / spacing. I could either scale down the icon a little bit or scale up the circle. I increased the viewbox size and circle values

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.1.4/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-shrink-0" viewBox="0 0 28 28">
  <circle cx="14" cy="14" r="14" class="text-green-200 fill-current"></circle>
  <path class="text-green-600 fill-current" d="M16.21 16.95a5 5 0 0 1-4.02 4.9l-3.85.77a1 1 0 0 1-.9-.27l-.71-.7a2 2 0 0 1 0-2.83l1.44-1.45a13.17 13.17 0 0 1-1.42-1.41L5.31 17.4a2 2 0 0 1-2.83 0l-.7-.7a1 1 0 0 1-.28-.9l.77-3.86a5 5 0 0 1 4.9-4.02h.86a13.07 13.07 0 0 1 12.82-5.47 1 1 0 0 1 .83.83A12.98 12.98 0 0 1 16.2 16.1v.85zm-4.41 2.94a3 3 0 0 0 2.41-2.94v-1.4a1 1 0 0 1 .47-.84A11.04 11.04 0 0 0 19.8 4.33 10.98 10.98 0 0 0 9.42 9.45a1 1 0 0 1-.85.47h-1.4a3 3 0 0 0-2.94 2.4l-.66 3.34.33.33 2.24-2.24a1 1 0 0 1 1.52.12 11.08 11.08 0 0 0 2.6 2.6 1 1 0 0 1 .12 1.52l-2.24 2.24.33.33 3.33-.67zM15 10a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z" />
</svg>
```

But how can I keep the icon centered? Do I have to use a flexbox and center it by myself? The checkmarks on the Tailwind website (link posted above) don't need a flexbox so maybe someone knows how to setup a little margin for the icon and still having it in the center?

---

A workaround for this would be

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.1.4/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="h-6 w-6 p-1 rounded-full bg-green-200">
  <svg class="text-green-600 fill-current" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <path d="M16.21 16.95a5 5 0 0 1-4.02 4.9l-3.85.77a1 1 0 0 1-.9-.27l-.71-.7a2 2 0 0 1 0-2.83l1.44-1.45a13.17 13.17 0 0 1-1.42-1.41L5.31 17.4a2 2 0 0 1-2.83 0l-.7-.7a1 1 0 0 1-.28-.9l.77-3.86a5 5 0 0 1 4.9-4.02h.86a13.07 13.07 0 0 1 12.82-5.47 1 1 0 0 1 .83.83A12.98 12.98 0 0 1 16.2 16.1v.85zm-4.41 2.94a3 3 0 0 0 2.41-2.94v-1.4a1 1 0 0 1 .47-.84A11.04 11.04 0 0 0 19.8 4.33 10.98 10.98 0 0 0 9.42 9.45a1 1 0 0 1-.85.47h-1.4a3 3 0 0 0-2.94 2.4l-.66 3.34.33.33 2.24-2.24a1 1 0 0 1 1.52.12 11.08 11.08 0 0 0 2.6 2.6 1 1 0 0 1 .12 1.52l-2.24 2.24.33.33 3.33-.67zM15 10a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

but I would really like to keep the circle and don't use a div because I think using the circle is a "cleaner" solution?

Comment: You should probably resize the SVG element using CSS instead of toying with it internally. If your SVG gets more complicated, it's going to be a nightmare.

Comment: @ Robert sorry, how do you mean that? Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/f0h7mrn2/ This only moves the whole image :/

Answer (score 2):

Just change the viewBox. Something like this perhaps. If you want a larger border make the viewBox bigger still but don't forget to adjust its origin too.

You can make the circle larger, but if you do leave the cx and cy of the circle alone.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@1.1.4/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<svg class="h-6 w-6 flex-shrink-0" viewBox="-2 -2 28 28">
  <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="12" class="text-green-200 fill-current"></circle>
  <path class="text-green-600 fill-current" d="M16.21 16.95a5 5 0 0 1-4.02 4.9l-3.85.77a1 1 0 0 1-.9-.27l-.71-.7a2 2 0 0 1 0-2.83l1.44-1.45a13.17 13.17 0 0 1-1.42-1.41L5.31 17.4a2 2 0 0 1-2.83 0l-.7-.7a1 1 0 0 1-.28-.9l.77-3.86a5 5 0 0 1 4.9-4.02h.86a13.07 13.07 0 0 1 12.82-5.47 1 1 0 0 1 .83.83A12.98 12.98 0 0 1 16.2 16.1v.85zm-4.41 2.94a3 3 0 0 0 2.41-2.94v-1.4a1 1 0 0 1 .47-.84A11.04 11.04 0 0 0 19.8 4.33 10.98 10.98 0 0 0 9.42 9.45a1 1 0 0 1-.85.47h-1.4a3 3 0 0 0-2.94 2.4l-.66 3.34.33.33 2.24-2.24a1 1 0 0 1 1.52.12 11.08 11.08 0 0 0 2.6 2.6 1 1 0 0 1 .12 1.52l-2.24 2.24.33.33 3.33-.67zM15 10a1 1 0 1 1 0-2 1 1 0 0 1 0 2z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks. I so I took your code and set the radius `r="16"` but then some of the bounds get cut off. Increasing the `h-6` or width did not help. How would I fix that? https://jsfiddle.net/vdtur18c/1/

Comment: Increase the viewBox size, but don't forget to adjust its origin too.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by origin exactly? I currently adjusted the sizes https://jsfiddle.net/902e1gk7/ and now the top and left borders get cut off. Do you mean using a CSS transform?

Comment: I think @ Robert meant this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp but I'm not sure

Comment: viewBox has 4 parameters, if you increase the height and width values you must adjust the first two x, y (or origin) parameters too. As you make the width bigger you need to make the x smaller (similarly for y and height).